# Number of bijective functions (two finite sets)

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Let $M$ and $N$ be finite sets, with $|M|=m$ and $|N|=n$.
>
> a)Find out the number of bijective functions $f: M \rightarrow N$. Look at the cases: $m \neq n$ and $m=n.$

Bijective: Every element in $N$ has exactly one partner in $M.$

$m\neq n:$ That means either $m < n $ or $m>n$.

If $m>n$ then wouldn't every element in $N$ have exactly one partner in $M$?

If $m<n$ then it wouldn't work, since some elements in $N$ wouldn't have a partner in $M$.

$m=n$: Here every element in $N$ will have exactly one partner in $M$.

So you can get a bijective functions if $m>n$ or $m=n$.

For $m=n$ number of bijective functions would be: $m$

For $m>n$ number of bijective functions would be: $n$

I'm not too sure on my answer.

Comment: A bijective function from a set to itself is called a "permutation."  It is well known that there are $n!$ permutations for a set with $n$ elements.  Search elsewhere on this site for a proof of this fact.  Next, it is well known that a bijection between two sets exists if and only if they have the same cardinality.  This is after all the *definition* of cardinality.  In the finite case, the cardinality of a set is simply the number of elements in the set.  When $m\neq n$, no bijections exist between the sets.  Don't confuse the word "bijection" with surjection.

Comment: If you wish for an example, consider the sets $M=\{a,b,c\}$ and $N=\{1,2,3\}$.  Among the available functions would be $\{(a,1),(b,2),(c,3)\},\{(a,1),(b,3),(c,2)\},\{(a,2),(b,1),(c,3)\},\{(a,2),(b,3),(c,1)\},\dots$ what we would normally shorthand as `123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that for any two bijections $f_1,f_2:M\to N$, we note that $f_1f_2^{-1}$ is an automorphism on $M$. So, the answer is simply the number of automorphisms of $M$, i.e., $m!$

Additionally, note that we could use the same argument with automorphisms of $N$, so that tells us the the answer is also $n!$. So, $m!=n!$, which for non-empty $M$, $N$ implies that $|M|=|N|$.